# How to get original Python error from a Py4JJavaError raised in a PySpark UDF

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, py4j

I am using PySpark UDFs to execute code on a Spark worker. If an exception is raised in the UDF this is wrapped in a `Py4JJavaError` and re-raised in Python. In order to process the error correctly I need the original error. Is there a way to get it from the `Py4JJavaError`?

The string representation of the original error is printed as part of the stack trace, so it would be possible to get at least the type of error by parsing the trace. However, this would be tedious and error-prone.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3]}))

@udf
def test(x):
    raise ValueError(f"Got {x}")

df = df.withColumn("B", test("A"))
df.show()
```

I would expect that I can extract the error that was originally raised, or at least the name of the error and/or the error message without parsing the stack trace.